# How to properly implement an error handler for spring cloud stream functions

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream

Im on spring cloud version 2021.0.3 and on spring boot 2.7.2

So I have read the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

And implemented it accordingly:

```java
@Bean
public Function<Message<MessageDto>, Message<MessageDto>> process() {
  return streamMessage -> {
    LOG.info("received message: {}", streamMessage.getPayload());

    final MessageDto message = streamMessage.getPayload();
    final MessageHeaders headers = streamMessage.getHeaders();

    throw new InvalidJsonException(); // custom RuntimeException to produce an error

    LOG.info("send message: {}", message);

    return MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(message)
        .copyHeadersIfAbsent(headers)
        .build();
  };
}

@Bean
public Consumer<ErrorMessage> myErrorHandler() {
  return v -> {
    LOG.error("houston we got a problem: {}", v);
  };
}
```

The config:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        error-handler-definition: myErrorHandler
      function:
        definition: process
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: inbound
          binder: kafka1
        process-out-0:
          destination: outbound
          binder: kafka1
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: kafka:9092
                      zkNodes: localhost:2181
                      replicationFactor: 1
                      requiredAcks: -1
                      configuration:
                        max.poll.interval.ms: 259200000 # 3d
                        max.poll.records: 1
```

The log:

```
received message: MessageDto{text='Hello World'}
received message: MessageDto{text='Hello World'}
received message: MessageDto{text='Hello World'}
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@610d37e1]; nested exception is InvalidJsonException
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@610d37e1]; nested exception is InvalidJsonException
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@610d37e1]; nested exception is InvalidJsonException
```

The retry mechanism kicks in thats why I receive the message 3 times and 3 times the default error handler logs and drops the message.

Nowhere in the logs I can find `houston we got a problem` so the consumer is not working!

When I do this instead:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = ERROR_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME)
public void handleError(final ErrorMessage error) {
  if (error.getOriginalMessage() == null) {
    LOG.error("original stream message is null!");
    return;
  }
  
  final Message<MessageDto> streamMessage = (Message<MessageDto>) error.getOriginalMessage();
  final MessageDto message = streamMessage.getPayload();
  final MessageHeaders headers = error.getHeaders();
  final Throwable e = error.getPayload();
  
  if (e instanceof InvalidJsonException) {
    LOG.error("We got our invalid json exception");
  }
}
```

It works **BUT** I will get a class cast exception. Seems like I cannot
get the original message from the ErrorMessage.

So whats the proper way to handle errors?

Comment: The payload of the `ErrorMessage` should be a `MessagingException`, which has a `failedMessage` property. The `originalMessage` property is before any conversion was done.

Comment: Yes. There is a `failedMessage` but it does not contain the message. It contains a byte array with, for me, unknown content. Same for the original message.
If I manually throw a `MessagingException` like `throw new MessagingException(message)` then the `originalMessage` and the `failedMessage` actually contains the message. Otherwise there is only the byte array of something.

Comment: Can you please raise an issue in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues as it looks like a bug

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/1054